# Grand(e) frère/soeur vs frère/soeur ainé(e) ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, société

Apparently these are both translations for *older brother* and *older sister.*

What is the difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***Grand frèr***e and ***grande sœur***, literally "big brother/sister", is the casual way to name an older brother or sister while *petit frère* and *petite sœur* (small brother/sister) mean younger brother/sister.

There are also specific and more literary names to define siblings order.

- ***Aîné(e)*** etymologically "born earlier"  (Old French *ainz né* from low Latin **antius natus*): means either the first-born → ***l***'aîné, or older → ***mon/son/ton/leur*** aîné(e).
- ***Puîné(e)*** etymologically "born later": any child but the first-born. ***Le*** puîné is the second born. This word is no longer used in modern French, but survived as "puisne" in English, as Frank wrote.
- ***Cadet(te)*** originally *Capdet from low Latin capitettus → Little head/chief; Captain*, is a synonymous of *puîné*. The reason why is that captains were often non heirs from Gascogne aristocratic families (D'Artagnan and the three musketeers are *cadets de Gascogne*). *Cadet* gave the English "caddie". When we say ***le*** cadet in modern French, it always means the second-born while *son cadet* means "his/her younger brother". Note that in Gascogne, like in many other southern provinces, the *aîné* was not necessarily the first born but the son chosen by the father to be his heir. Consequently a *cadet* could well be the first-born.
- ***Benjamin(e)***, originally both the favorite and younger child of Jacob in the Bible, used in French to name the last-born child.

Comment: Je me demande quels étaient exactement les prérogatives de l'ainé, historiquement, et s'il y avait des différences en matière d'héritage, notamment. Il serait aussi intéressant de voir si la situation était similaire dans les pays anglo-saxons, ou si c'est une spécificité française (ou continentale). Ce _bagage_ (avec 2 _g_;-) historique pourrait être intéressant pour bien transmettre les associations avec le mot, dans certains contextes.

Comment: @Frank Quelle spécificité ?

Comment: Que l'ainé ait une place privilégiée en terme d'éducation, carrière, ou accession au trône.

Comment: @Frank La primogéniture était la coutume la plus répandue en Europe. Elle n'était pas toujours automatique dans la noblesse française, le porteur du titre pouvant souvent désigner librement son successeur parmi ses fils. La différence de la France avec beaucoup d'autres pays est plutôt la loi salique qui reniait aux femmes la possession de titres et des terres associées.

Comment: Oui, je savais pour la loi des Francs saliens. Pour ce qui est de la primogéniture, je crois aussi savoir qu'il y avait un "order" préférentiel pour l'éducation: l'ainé était destiné au métier des armes, puis venait le commerce, puis à la fin, une carrière ecclésiastique?

Comment: @Frank Cet ordre préférentiel est une idée reçue. L'aîné ou l'héritier désigné pouvait servir dans l'armée, parfois à un grade élevé (~ officiers supérieurs/généraux) si la famille était fortunée, les cadets le pouvaient aussi mais plutôt comme officiers subalternes ou embrassaient une carrière ecclésiastique. Quant au commerce, surtout pas ! C'était une activité de roturiers. Un noble perdait cette qualité (dérogeance) temporairement ou définitivement s'il s'adonnait à une activité manuelle, commerciale ou industrielle en dehors de quelques rares exceptions: verriers, grand commerce maritime.

Answer (score 4):

It's a difference in language level, like in English between *big bro* and *older brother*. *Grand* is more colloquial. *Ainé* is more formal, and in fact significantly more so than English's *older brother* would be (maybe it's even closer to *elder brother*).

Answer (score 3):

I think *aîné*'s "first" meaning in French is *first born* (although coming from the Low Latin *antius natus*, where *antius* is only the comparative, not superlative, of *ante*) , which is not necessarily the case for *grand frère/soeur*, which would just mean *older than*. [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ain%C3%A9) gives: *Fils aîné, fille aînée. Né(e) le premier (la première), le plus âgé ou la plus âgée par rapport aux autres enfants de la même famille. Synon. premier-né. Anton. cadet, puîné, second*.

In an expression like:

> Voici l'aîné.

where you are introducing your children, it is certainly your *first born* that you are introducing.

However, in the expression:

> Je suis son aînée de cinq ans.

*aînée* just means *older than* again.

*Aîné* has yet another meaning in, e.g.:

> Des activités sportives pour les aînés.

Where it means *older folks*.

So we have three possible meanings for *aîné*, whereas *grand frère/soeur* just means *older sibling*. Note also that there is a cultural baggage associated to *aîné* which biases the meaning towards *first born*, as historically, *le fils aîné* would get preferential treatment over other brothers/sisters (typically getting a better education and the most promising career).

Note also that *grand frère/soeur* are in a more relaxed language register.

The opposite of *aîné* in the sense of first born would be: *puîné* (lit.: *born next*) or *cadet*. *Puisne* is attested as a legal term of art in British English to mean "inferior in rank" (the *aîné* getting all the attention, better education, better position...), but *aîné* doesn't seem to have made it to English.

Comment: *Aîné* first meaning is *born earlier*, not *first born* (Old French *ainz né* from Low Latin **antius natus*). *Mon aîné* doesn't (necessarily) introduce the first born of your siblings but just one of your older brothers.

Comment: @jlliagre - je m'apprêtais à changer ma réponse, mais CNRTL donne: _Fils aîné, fille aînée. Né(e) le premier (la première), le plus âgé ou la plus âgée par rapport aux autres enfants de la même famille. Synon. premier-né. Anton. cadet, puîné, second_. Je ne sais plus quoi faire.

Comment: Il faut lire la page du TLFi jusqu'au bout

Comment: "antius natus" = né "plus avant", c'est vrai que l'interprétation peut se discuter.

Comment: De toute façon, « mon aîné » ne signifie pas forcément qu'il s'agit de l'aîné de la fratrie.

Comment: Il est possible que le sens français soit décalé par rapport au Latin. Mais l'entrée de CNRTL n'est pas ambiguë dans son premier sens pour l'adjectif, surtout avec un synonyme: _premier-né_.